# app structure in Laravel 4 and class does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have structured my app as the following

note: "MyCMS" is a folder inside the "app" directory of laravel root directory

http://paste.laravel.com/POt

the problem is that whenever i try to access the route "admin/users"

i get the following error

```
Class \MyCMS\Admin\UserController does not exist
```

any ideas where the problem might be ?

Comment: I have already run -> artisan dump-autoload command

Comment: run _composer_ with updating composer.json with namespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `UserController.php`, it should be
`namespace MyCMS\Admin\Controllers;` not `namespace MyCMS\Admin;`

And a side note, I don't think you can just call `$this->package('MyCMS/Admin');` when it's in your app directory.  If you look into laravel's [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/ServiceProvider.php) for the package method, it's actually guessing the path for your "package" and going two levels up to get the resources. It's a very specific file structure.

Answer (score 1):

sometime we face this issue then we should use `<?php` instead of `<?` in UserController.php

Then use composer du or composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your issues is quite simple. Packages don't go in the app directory of Laravel.

If you want to create a package, do so with the following command:

```
php artisan workbench vendor/package --resources
```

This will then create a `workbench` folder in your Laravel installation, where a pre-defined directory structure will be at the ready for your newly created package.

```
/src
    /Vendor
        /Package
            PackageServiceProvider.php
    /config
    /lang
    /migrations
    /views
/tests
/public
```

You may then register the provider by adding it to the providers array in the `app/config/app.php` file. After a `composer dump-autoload` your package should be ready to use in your app.

See [this section](http://laravel.com/docs/packages) in Laravel's documentation on how to create packages properly.

Comment: Ok, ignoring "package" word in the question, is there a way to get the above to work for code organization purpose ?